# Is there a visualizer for jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery

No, I'm not talking about the visualizer plugin.

There are cheap or free tools to visualize the results of XPath queries, or Regex.

Example:
[image]

[image]

Is there a similar tool that helps one visualize the results of jQuery selectors?
I know it wouldn't be difficult to build... Just wanna know if one exists yet.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a great jQuery documentation site is Visual jQuery, http://visualjquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this one does the job pretty well:

http://www.woods.iki.fi/interactive-jquery-tester.html

Answer (score 3):

Use firebug. Open the console. Run something like this:

```
$("p").css('background-color', 'blue');
```

and press 'Run'.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `$('div.product').get()` into Firebug or whatever console you're using to get a list of matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

For Safari, the Web Inspector has a console you can use to achieve this.